# Unable to expand .zip (Operation not permitted) zipped with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have a directory with several files. I want to create an archive with some of these files (e. g. only files with names listed in some array)
That's my code:

```
import zipfile
import os

def zip_files(report_dir):
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('report.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_STORED)
    rep = ['1', '2', 'new']
    print('RRREP ', rep)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(report_dir):
        for file in files:
            title = file.title().split('_')[0]
            if title in rep:
                zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))

    zipf.close()


zip_files('')
```

When I try to expand the resulting archive, I receive a message

> Unable to expand "report.zip" (Error 1 - Operation not permitted)

If I add all files from the directory (= if I remove `if...`-code), the archive can be opened without problems.

Comment: Have you tried with `with ... as zipf` clause instead of `zipf = ...`?

Comment: "When I try to expand the resulting archive, I receive a message ". What are you using to do that?

Comment: Looks like a MacOS issue, cf https://www.google.com/search?q=%28Error+1+-+Operation+not+permitted%29&oq=%28Error+1+-+Operation+not+permitted%29

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Archive Utility, mac double click

Comment: have you tried opening the .zip with some python code to list/extract the contents? maybe the zipfile is empty and the mac stuff doesn't like it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks, it really was empty. 
I expected filenames to be uppercase (because they are really named in uppercase), but for some reasons python script got mixed. So no files for my conditions. Crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that creating an empty zip file can cause some issues to some external archivers.

Your filter doesn't match anything. In the future, you could protect your archive creation with a flag and report an error if nothing matched:

```
at_least_one_match = False

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(report_dir):
    for file in files:
        title = file.title().split('_')[0]
        if title in rep:
            at_least_one_match = True
            zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))


if not at_least_one_match:
    raise Exception("No files were added. Archive is empty/corrupt")
```